# Leaflet: How to deal with overlapping lines?

Tags: leaflet

How can I deal with overlapping lines in the Leaflet map library?

[image: problem illustration]

I download geoJSON from the server sid and draw it right onto the map. If there are two identical entries, Leaflet draws them twice. This could be fixed by finding exact duplicated on the server side.

That however doesn't work for different datasets sharing some of the same space. As a result parts of both are drawn onto the same spot.

Comment: In your scenario, Leaflet will draw the orange line and the blue line separately. If they happen to overlap, Leaflet will render it as shown. In this case, what is your desired outcome? Should the orange line get trimmed? The blue line get trimmed? What do you want to happen?

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

It appears that the lines are being rendered with the default Leaflet Polyline opacity of 0.5. If you were instantiating the Polylines yourself in code, you could override the opacity to make the lines opaque in this manner:

```
var myPolyLine = new L.Polyline( myPoints, { opacity: 1 } );
```

The line that would appear on top would then be the line that you added to the map last (one or the other is going to be on top, unless you make them both opaque and the same color). But this may be moot if you are loading in geoJSON directly and don't have control over how Leaflet renders it.